# Gradle equivalent for mvn clean verify

Tags: maven, gradle

I have a project which is based on gradle .I have to run the command which is equivalent for mvn clean verify .As I am new to both gradle and maven ,and have been exposed to only 3 command of both .I want to run a gradle equivalent for mvn clean verify .I searched on websites but still have not got the answer .Can some please help me to know what will be the gradle equivalent for "mvn clean verify"

Comment: Not sure what "verify" does, but you might want to compare it to "check" which would yield something similar to "gradle clean check"; however, you should really spend some time learning about the tools you use rather than just blindly running commands. It will save you a lot of headache down the road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gradle clean verify`

or if you are using gradle wrapper:

`./gradlew clean verify`

Comment: I don't agree with this answer. Even the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html#migmvn:build_lifecycle) do clearly state: "_mvn verify -> Use the **check** task provided by the Base Plugin. This runs all verification tasks that are attached to it, which typically includes the unit tests, any static analysis tasks and others._". If you would use the `test` command, you would skip other tasks like integration tests and analysers.

Comment: I got "Task 'verify' not found in root project". It's worth to mention what prerequisites are.